# "native "AssertionError_throwNew" " error with Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function that checks if a document exists or not, if exists returns true otherwise false :

```
Future<bool> checkMissingId(String id) async {

  String str = id.toLowerCase();
  String letter = str[0];
  String path = letter + "/" + str;

  try {
    final snapShot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc(str).get();

    if (snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists) {
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return false;
       }
    }
```

But when I call it from here (after save and validate form ) :

```
 Future<void> _submit() async {
    //Create Artist and send it to the database
    if (_validateAndSaveForm()) {
      await checkMissingId(userNameF);
    }
}
```

All freezes and it opens a new file called "errors_patch.dart" with this exception :

```
static _doThrowNew(int assertionStart, int assertionEnd, Object? message)
      native "AssertionError_throwNew";
```

I think the problem is that checkMissingId is of type Future and maybe I'm not handling futures in the right way...But the error highlights also `await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc(str).get();` so I don't know exactly how isolate the problem.
This is the stack :

```
assert(isValidCollectionPath(collectionPath),

await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc(str).get();
 with a red quotes : 

_AssertionError ('package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart': Failed assertion: line 74 pos 12: 'isValidCollectionPath(collectionPath)': a collection path must point to a valid collection.)
 await checkMissingId(userNameF);
```

Maybe it depends by wrong document path from Firestore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are passing the wrong collection name in this line:

```
final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path).doc(str).get();
```

because, your path variable is this:

```
String path = letter + "/" + str; // I guess here is something wrong
```

Your collection name would be a fixed string as shown below in this screenshot (comments, posts, users etc):

[image: Collection name]

Comment: I'm sure that these collections didn't exist...But I thought Firebase would create them...Maybe Firebase will do it when I use the "set", "get" instead needs of an existing collection?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You must create a collection first by using the `set` method. Only then, you should use the `get` method. Firebase will not create a collection if you use the `get` method.

Comment: Welcome, buddy. Happy to help.